# How can I traverse the Blazor component's children?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

How can I traverse the Blazor component's children and browse its mark-up elements?
My task is to find any HTML elements with attribute like SecurityGroup="GroupName" and modify, say, `<input>` element to `<label>`. Or remove `<input>` at all.
I tried to define the RenderTreeBuilder delegate and get Frames but it seems no HTML stuff can be obtained.

Here is the demo project for what I am trying to accomplish: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/rp5b0q6kjqguyj4k5zfd6/ComponentTreeTraversing.zip?rlkey=jlb9jh0l2sgk0hn54vxy7lch8&dl=0

It uses the JS Mutation Observer, try the security group Evaluator and see how controls get secured. See the Employee Evaluation. It is not implemented but it is where I want the virtual DOM get traversing. Thoughts?

Comment: Simple answer is you can't, but you're approaching the problem from the wrong direction.

Comment: There is no "wrong directions". The only thing we happen to encounter is the platform inability. That's the paradigm I profess. Remember Silverlight? The thing I am asking about could be done there with ease (I omit all other Silverlight deficiencies here to avoid the deviation from the subject). Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: [Polite] I should have said - probably.  Everyone quotes, Silverlight - but that's a "broken record"!  What you want to do is transverse the DOM, which you can only do in the browser i.e. through JsInterop.  The problem with that is if you change the DOM then you can break the app.  You'll have the same issues with any SPA.  By wrong direction, I mean wrong approach to the problem.  Can you provide a [mre] of what you are trying to achieve, your description is a bit succinct.

Comment: I don't see a reason you must do this, but I have provided a solution in case your specific situation demands it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [MVVM toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/)
2. Inject IMessenger to every component that you want to make those changes via `@inject IMessenger Messenger`
3. Create a message type for each of the activity that you want to do
   eg. `public record ReplaceInputWithLabel()`
4. Register for the message in each razor component that you want this change to happen. The cleanest way to do this is to ensure that the component implements `IRecipient<ReplaceInputWithLabel>`. So, declare the following in the razor file

> ```
> @implements IRecepient<ReplaceInputWithLabel>
> ```

and

> ```
> public async void Receive(ReplaceInputWithLabel msg)
> ```

5. In the implementation you can make the necessary changes to the component markup via state.

> ```
> bool IsLabelInsteadOfInput {get;set;}
>
> public async void Receive(ReplaceInputWithLabel msg)
> {
>   IsLabelInsteadOfInput = true;
>   await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
> }
> ```

Your markup would look like:

> ```
> @if(IsLabelInsteadOfInput) 
> {
>     <input type="text"> 
> }else 
> {
>     <label></label> 
> }
> ```

Now,when you send the message to change input to label, all components that are registered for this message will update their own state. You can add more functionality by enriching ReplaceInputWithLabel / creating more message types / addition fields to the records and apply conditional logic.

Comment: Hi Mayur. Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I am looking for the way of Blazor DOM traversing, not MVVM implementation, Messaging Center or so. Your solution supposes me to know in advance which place or element is protected and wrap it up with appropriate markup. The DOM traversing will give you more like applying an attribute to a div and all div's children pick up its security level regardless of what your markup defines. That's way flexible and so far I do not know the solution. The MVVM is good but it is just an entourage. Thanks

Comment: Help me understand this: when you render the elements for the first time, you know which elements have SecurityGroup="GroupName" tag, right? Let them inherit from the base class that listens to the MVVM message.
Also, you can manipulate DOM using JSInterop. But it is like trying to do C++ style malloc in a language runtime that has its own automatic garbage collection. It is not designed for these situations and hence, creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: >you know which elements have SecurityGroup="GroupName" tag, right
Correct. Until the container, defined at run-time, overrides it

>you can manipulate DOM using JSInterop
Right. And that's what I do in my demo project attached. More specifically, I use DOM mutations observer for that. 
if div has a security level Read-only, any element inside with the security attribute should be Read-only even if it initially is ReadWrite. it needs the children enlisting aka control-tree traversing. It should occur on pre-render step to make sure the DOM and virtual DOM are in sync. Thanks